# How in Sinatra would I check that the term the user has input into a form already exists in your database?

Tags: sql, ruby, sinatra

Making a budget app while learning to use Ruby/Sinatra/SQL. Part of it involves letting the user add new vendors that they can assign transactions to. My add transaction and add vendor functions both work, but one thing I'd like to do is be able to throw up an error if the vendor that the user is trying to add - eg 'Amazon' is already in the database, before returning to my index of vendors.

The closest that I've come to getting something working is making the name column of the vendor table UNIQUE. But if I enter a name that's already in existence in the field, I get the "PG::UniqueViolation" error.

Is there a way to tell Sinatra that you don't want this error to flag up, you just want to redirect back to the index of vendors without the repeated value.

My working submission form currently looks like:

```
<div id="new-transaction">
  <form action="/vendors/create" method="POST">

    <label for="name">New vendor name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="vendorName" />

    <input type="submit" value="Add new vendor" id="btn-new-vendor">

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Generally people use an ORM to handle their database validations. It's good practice to also add DB-level validations as well, but using an ORM makes things a lot easier. [This](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-working-with-datamapper--net-19622) is a good tutorial for using [datamapper](http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html) with Sinatra - it's an ORM that, like Sinatra, is intentionally simple to set up. You can also use Rails' [activerecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) in Sinatra without too much trouble.

Comment: ORMs don't solve all your problems especially if you want to learn SQL. Datamapper is also a bit outdated... I'd recommend sequel which is the closest you can get in Ruby when it comes to Ruby-like SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and use that error as a response to work with in your app. You can add a `begin/rescue/end` block to your method:

```
# some code before
begin
  DB.add_your_vendor_method
rescue
  go_back_to_index
end
show_value_to_user
# some code after
```

You can make that block error specific, too. There is some nice write up on ruby error handling over at http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html